# Scaling vector field marker arrow based on attribute?

Tags: qgis, vector, symbology, style, markers

I have discovered how to create vector lines to indicate flow direction and velocities. With a "vector field marker" symbol layer type, the lines lengths vary based on the data attributes. However, when using an arrow as a symbol layer type, I can only seem to get the line to scale and not the arrow head. I would like to scale the arrow head proportionally with the line based on the data attributes. Is there a way to do this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question by adding a screenshot of what you have set in the `Vector field marker` dialog?

Comment: @mgri I have added the screenshot you mentioned. I set the X and Y attributes to the correspond with my X and Y velocity vectors from my model output and it automatically scales the default vector field lines. When I Click on "simple line" beneath "Line" in the marker tree, I select "Arrow" as my Symbol Layer Type. This is where I get hung up and am unable to scale the arrow head proportionally with the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should get the desired output by recurring to a custom expression.

Firstly, click on the `Edit...` button for the `Head length` option:

[image]

Then, type this expression:

```py
length(
 make_line(
  $geometry,
  make_point(
   $x +  "Vel_X_ft_p_s",
   $y +  "Vel_Y_ft_p_s"
   )
  )
 ) / 3
```

which is saying, in an imaginary way:

> "For the current feature, draw a head having a length which is 1/3
>   of the total length of the line."

You can obviously change the `3` number as you want and apply a similar rule if you want to do the same for the `Head thickness` parameter (you have just learned how to do it).

Applying the edit on the `Head length` parameter as above seems to work for me:

[image]

Comment: This is on the right track for what I am trying to do. I appreciate the help. When I tried this, it kind of brought QGIS to it's knees. Each point in my data does however have a velocity magnitude value. Does it make more sense to scale the arrow heads using magnitude and how would that change the code?

Comment: @spearl Could you elaborate? My solution should already lead to proportionally scale the head length of the arrow and it seems a good way of solving the issue. If you have the magnitude stored in a field, you may simply use the expression `"magnitude"/3`, but I don't know how the solution would change and if it would be better.

Comment: @mgri +1 Very nice solution, that also can bb applied for the thickness.

Comment: @mgri You are correct. I think this should work. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

An alternative more simple approach would be to use a SVG marker instead of a vector marker field, with just setting the scale and rotation.

SVG Style:

[image]

Attribute table:

[image]

Map:

[image]

If you want the hydrology map with the same arrow line width, this might not suite you, since the entire styled object is scaled.

Comment: Thanks for this. For this to work, I would have to calculate the rotation angle for each point before bringing it into QGIS. That is totally reasonable, but I wanted to avoid manipulating the raw data s much as possible for a more seamless procedure. I am currently using the vector field renderer plugin to get the look I am after, which temporarily solves my problem.