# Explanation of vector field marker and its options in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

When I go to the symbology of a point feature layer I can change the symbol layer type from a simple marker to a vector field marker. What does the vector field marker do and in what situations is it useful?

Let's say my point feature has a field called `"id"` and I have 5 points with `"id"`'s from 1 to 5.

When I add the field `"id"` as X-attribute I get a horizontal line of markers. The higher the `"id"` value the longer the horizontal line.

But how long is the line? And what's the purpose of the other options like vector field type, the direction of rotation or the angle unit?

I am looking for good explanation websites. I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

There are several websites that I may refer you to:

- [Scaling vector field marker arrow based on attribute?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237977/scaling-vector-field-marker-arrow-based-on-attribute)
- [QGIS change Vector Marker Size](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZG3SuDx2Vs0)
- [The Vector Field Marker](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#the-vector-field-marker)
- [Search *'qgis vector field marker'* on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=qgis+vector+field+marker)